# Codepro Analytix for eclipse 3.2

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, codepro, eclipse-3.2

I am using RAD 7.0.0.8( which uses eclipse 3.2). I tried to find a eclipse 3.2 compatible Codepro Analytix plugin, but to no avail. So I installed (copied-pasted unzipped contents to "features" and "plugins" folders appropriately and run eclipse with "-clean" cmd line arg) the eclipse 3.4 compatible version of the plugin. 
Eclipse started well but when I try to access or use codepro tools, an exception is thrown( different for each feature) saying "some-class-here" cannot be instantiated.
Please help me with this issue. 
Also is there a way to get Codepro Analytix zip for eclipse 3.2?

I am badly in need of this plugin. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As far as I know, the first version of CodePro was made for 3.4.
It is not possible to use plugins in earlier version then they were made for.

Comment: But as this page below says, it should be supported right. https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/requirements

Comment: Hm, that's strange... they say, it supports down to eclipse 2.1, but only offer update sites for 3.4 and later.
Base on this forum thread http://forums.instantiations.com/topic-7-1207.html CP 4.5.1 should work with RAD7.0. Yet I wasn't able to find a working download link for that particular version...